# Intuition: If $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then $a\leq b$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, intuition

I am reading Tom Apostol's Analysis and come across this theorem.

Should $a \leq b$ if $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$?

I don't doubt the proof in the book but I don't understand the intuition or geometric explanation behind this. Could somebody shed some light on this equation? I just started studying analysis on my own.$\ \ $

Comment: It means that if $a$ isn't bigger than $b$, then $a \le b$.

Comment: I suggest you concentrate on the words **for all**.  As often happens in basic analysis, it isn't the algebra that really matters, it's the logic.  Hope this helps.

Comment: For any real number we have either $a>b$ or $a\le b$ (but not both at the same time) and since the former yields a contradiction for a particular $\varepsilon$ as the book have shown what is the only alternative? And for the intuition behind think about the meaning of the term "for all".

Comment: Just take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$

Comment: @sidht, *why* limits preserve $\le$? BTW limits don't preserve $<$.

Comment: @Martin But he has $\leq$ not $<$

Comment: @sidht, yes. My point is that the preservation of inequalities by limits isn't obvious (and in the strict case is false).

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, I agree it is false for $<$, but isn't it true for $\leq$?

Comment: @sidht, yes, is true. But not *obvious*. Proving it requires the same or more work than proving the original question.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, but we know that if $g(x) \leq f(x) + \epsilon$, it certainly is true when you take limit. This is just a  special case. I am still not seeing the problem…; in fact I thought since (as a weaker statement), if $a < b + \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon >0$, then it is safe to take limit to prove the result.

Comment: @sidht, one more time: my point is that the preservation of $\le$ by limits isn't *obvious*, and the proof of it isn't  significantly easier than the proof of the OP question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418499/limits-preserve-weak-inequalities.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, oh okay that's what you meant. The link helped clarified.

Answer (score 21):

Draw a number line. Mark the point $b$. Where can you mark $a$? Every number greater than $b$ may be written as $b+\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon >0$. Then $a\leqslant b+\varepsilon$ says every number greater than $b$ is also greater than $a$. Thus, you erase all what comes after $b$. The only remaining choices are the numbers to the left or $b$ itself.

Comment: +Upvote. consummate intuition.

Answer (score 12):

The contrapostive of this statement says if $a>b$ then there exist $\epsilon>0$ such that $a>b+\epsilon$, take $\epsilon = (a-b)/2$.

Comment: does this expatiate on the intuition?

Comment: I don't remember to explain "intuition" when the question was asked.

Comment: @Tucker Rapu nonetheless, the intuition really should really be a sense of "approximation": if something is true with $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small, then the statement probably works when $\epsilon=0$. But I myself don't find it that helpful to talk about intuition in this case.

Comment: but question questioned for 'intuition'? I don't understand your first comment.

Comment: I don't understand it either now, lol.

Answer (score 1):

What is the possible alternative to $a≤b$ ?

Obviously, it is $b<a$.
Is it possible that at the same time  $a≤b+ϵ$ for all $ϵ>0$ **and** $b<a$.

OK, let us consider that possibility — in naive geometric sense it means that $b$ is to the left of $a$.

But real numbers have that great property — if we have two different numbers, there exists a number "between" them. So, for some small $ϵ$, for example, the $ϵ$ is equal to half of distance between $a$ and $b$, it is true that $b+ϵ<a$.

Comment: Your last sentence makes no sense.

Answer (score -3):

Assume for contradiction $a > b$. However we can pick $\epsilon = (a-b)/2 > 0$ so that $a > b + \epsilon$, a contradiction of our original assumption $a \le b + \epsilon$. Imagine the real line:

$$
....\underbrace{b ......... b+\epsilon}_{\text{dist of } (a-b)/2} ......... a ....
$$

The same trick works for $a - \epsilon \le b + \epsilon$ using $\epsilon = (a-b)/3$.