# proving if $0 \le a \le \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon \gt 0$ then $a=0$

Tags: inequality

Suppose $a$ is a real number and we know that
$$0 \le a \le \varepsilon$$
for every $\varepsilon \gt 0$.  I need to show that $a=0$.  The book I am working out of already has shown by contradiction that $0 \le a \lt \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon \gt 0$ implies that $a=0$.  I can honestly say I am confused, since if $a=\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon \gt 0$, then $a\neq{0}$

Comment: It has to hold for all $\epsilon$, not just for $\epsilon = a$.

Comment: But isn't $a=\varepsilon$ a contradiction to what I'm trying to prove since then $a\neq{0}$?

Comment: Hint: Suppose $a > 0$. If $0 \leq a \leq \varepsilon$ holds for every $\varepsilon > 0$ then take $\varepsilon = \frac a2 > 0$.

Comment: Why do you believe $a=\varepsilon$?  Even if $a\leq \varepsilon$ everywhere, there can only be one $\varepsilon$ for which the equality occurs; all the rest must be $<$.  (And in fact, you can probably see intuitively that the equality must occur at the lowest possible value.)

Comment: It's all about the order that you pick your $a$ and $\epsilon$. First, you pick $a$. THEN for every single $\epsilon > 0$, your condition holds.

You can pick $\epsilon = a$, but you could also pick it to be even smaller (assuming $a > 0$).

Comment: I believe $a=\varepsilon$ since we are told that $0\le a \le \varepsilon$, so isn't there a number $a$ that equals $\varepsilon$ and it can't be $0$ since $\varepsilon \gt 0$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition: If $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon&gt;0$ then $a\leq b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\forall\varepsilon,0\le a \le \varepsilon$ then either $a>0$ or $a=0$. If $a>0$, then setting $\varepsilon<a$ we have $0\le a\le\varepsilon<a$ a contradiction. Then $a=0$.

Comment: This is so confusing...aren't we told that $a\le \varepsilon$?  How can then you say $\varepsilon \lt a$?

Comment: Because it holds **for all** $\varepsilon>0$. If you say that $a>0$, then I can choose a $0<\varepsilon<a$ and reached a contradiction is like a game.

Comment: So basically, as long as you can always find a number between $0$ and $a$, you have a contradiction to $a \gt 0$?

Comment: $a\in \mathbb{R}$, then either $a<0,a=0,a>0$ by the trichotomy. Clearly $a<0$ is not possible. Then either $a=0$ or $a>0$, but the latter yields a contradiction, because we can always pick some $0<\varepsilon<a$ because by hypothesis it holds **for all** numbers $>0$. Then what is the only alternative.

Comment: Okay...i see i think.  It's the contradiction.  Your inequality in your answer makes sense now.  That seems to me not easy to figure out (i'm a novice at this style of proof...)

Comment: It's similar in nature to the "game" a number bigger than all the numbers. If you say that is $N$  then I say $N+1$.