# $x,y$ are real, $x<y+\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon>0$. How to prove $x \le y$?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, real-numbers

$x,y \in \mathbb R$ are such that  $x \lt y + \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ Then prove $x \le y$.

Comment: You mean $x<y+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, right? Assume the opposite to reach a contradiction.

Comment: for any $\epsilon \gt 0$

Comment: This isn't a problem of proving something we are uncertain of.  This is a problem of using a set of axioms to prove something that had damn well better be true.  So to approach this problem, you *must* specify what your axioms are.  Find a reference for an axioma of real numbers.  If this problem came from a book, check which theorems the chapter introduced and see if you can use those.

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x > y $, then $ x - y > 0 $. Hence, we can choose $\epsilon = x - y$ and we obtain

$$ x < y + \epsilon = y + x - y = x $$

Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

If not. Pick $\epsilon=x-y$.