# Prove : $|x - y| \leqslant \epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon > 0$ iff $x = y$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I have to do this exercise for my math study, and I'm having trouble with doing the second part of it.

Let $x, y, \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Prove: $|x - y| \leqslant \epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon > 0 \Leftrightarrow x = y$

I think I have the left implication $\Leftarrow$:

Assume $x = y \Rightarrow x - y = 0 \Rightarrow|x - y| = 0 = |0| \Rightarrow|x - y| = 0 < \epsilon \Rightarrow |x - y| \leqslant \epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon > 0 \in \mathbb{R}$

Is this argument correct?

For the right implication, I do only have an idea of how to prove it. I think I have to assume first that $x > y$ and then $x < y$ and get a contradiction form both.

Could you please explain me the right implication and tell me if my left implication is correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of looking at two cases, you could assume [WLOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) that $x>y$, that means $x-y>0$. Choose $\varepsilon$ positive, but smaller than $x-y$, e.g. $\varepsilon = (x-y)/2$.

Comment: @StackTD But proving something WLOG is just a proof by cases which gets swept under the rug.

Comment: Of course... What I means was: you can avoid having to show both cases explicitly, if you use the symmetry/WLOG-argument (as a response to "*I have to assume first that $x>y$ and then $x<y$ and get a contradiction form both"*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition: If $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon&gt;0$ then $a\leq b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition about : $a = b \iff | a − b| &lt; \epsilon$, for every $\epsilon &gt; 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436553/intuition-about-a-b-iff-a-%e2%88%92-b-epsilon-for-every-epsilon-0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your left implication is OK. For the right implication, if $x\neq y$, just take $\epsilon=\frac{|x-y|}{2}$ to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: Note that it doesn't need to be a contradiction, contrapositive and direct proof work with the same idea.

Comment: Git Gud, I don't see a way to find a direct proof for the right implication. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 8):

$( \Rightarrow ) $ I will prove by contraposition. Our affirmative states that:

$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 \; ( | x - y | < \epsilon ) \implies x = y
$$

The contrapositive is

$$
\lnot ( x = y ) \implies \lnot \forall \epsilon > 0 \; ( | x - y | < \epsilon ) \\
x \neq y  \implies  \exists \epsilon > 0 \; \lnot ( | x - y | < \epsilon ) \\
x \neq y \implies \exists \epsilon > 0 \; ( | x - y | \ge \epsilon )
$$

Therefore, if we prove the contrapositive, we have proved the affirmative. We need to find an $ \epsilon \le | x - y |$.

Let $ \epsilon = \frac{|x-y|}{2} $, since $ x \neq y $, without loss of generality,  let $ x > y $, that implies $ x - y > 0 $, since we have    $ | x - y | = x - y > 0 \implies | x - y | > 0 $.

Therefore $ | x - y | \ge \epsilon = \frac{|x-y|}{2} \implies 2 |x-y| \ge |x-y| $. That is true for all positive values, since we have proved our contraposition our initial hypothesis is valid.

$ ( \Leftarrow ) $ Direct proof. Let $ x = y \implies x - y = 0 \implies | x - y | = | 0 | < \epsilon \;\;\; \square$

Answer (score 5):

Let $x\neq y$. Then show that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $|x-y|>\epsilon$. (For example $\epsilon =\frac{|x-y|}{2}$, which satisfies $\epsilon>0$ because of our starting assumption.) The result follows from contraposition.