# $\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists x,y\ |x−y|=\epsilon/2.$ Why isn't it a counterexample to $\forall \epsilon>0\ (|x−y|<\epsilon) \implies x=y$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying $\forall \epsilon>0(|x−y|<\epsilon) \implies x=y$ at the moment and there is something I can not figure out.
I really understand the logic behind the contrapositive demonstration in this post:
[Prove : $|x - y| \leqslant \epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon > 0$ iff $x = y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166255/prove-x-y-leqslant-epsilon-forall-epsilon-0-iff-x-y)
but I also can not understand why the logic below is false:

$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists x,y\ (x\neq y \land |x−y|=\epsilon/2<\epsilon),$ which looks like a counter example of the initial statement.

I'm I making a mistake?

(I'm French so sorry in advance for any potential grammar or spelling mistake)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the post that you are referring to, $x$ and $y$ are *given* and can not be chosen depending on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you. I finally managed to see the mistake in my argumentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition: If $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon&gt;0$ then $a\leq b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b)

Answer (score 3):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. If you take $x,y\in\Bbb R$ such that $|x-y|=\frac\varepsilon2$, then indeed $|x-y|<\varepsilon$ and $x\ne y$. But it's *not* true that $|x-y|$ is smaller than *every* number greater than $0$ (which is what the assertion $(\forall\varepsilon>0):|x-y|<\varepsilon$ means). Just note that, for instance, $|x-y|>\frac\varepsilon3$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I finally understand the mistake in my argumentation !

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1468292/42969 is very close, is it good enough as a duplicate target?

Comment: @MartinR It's not clear-cut to me  but I will not oppose it.

Answer (score 1):

Your
$$\forall \epsilon>0(|x−y|<\epsilon) \implies x=y\tag1$$
is ambiguous:

- You seem to interpret $(1)$ as$$\forall x,y\quad\forall \epsilon>0\quad\left(|x−y|<\epsilon\implies x=y\right)\tag2$$or equivalently$$\forall \epsilon>0\quad\forall x,y\quad\left(|x−y|<\epsilon\implies x=y\right),\tag3$$the negation of which is$$\exists\epsilon>0\quad\exists x,y\quad\left(|x−y|<\epsilon\text{ and }x\ne y\right).\tag4$$
  You correctly prove $$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists x,y\quad\left(|x−y|<\epsilon\text{ and }x\ne y\right),$$
  which implies $(4)$ and therefore disproves $(3)$ and $(2).$
- The intended meaning of $(1)$ is however the proposition proved in the post you linked to:
  $$\forall x,y\quad\left[\left(\forall \epsilon>0\quad|x−y|<\epsilon\right)\implies x=y\right].\tag5$$
  The parenthesis make a big difference between $(2)$ (false) and $(5)$ (true).

Answer (score 0):

The correct original statement is: "if $\lvert x-y \rvert \lt \epsilon$ holds for all $\epsilon \gt 0$, then $x=y$". When this statement is true, your proposed counter-example cannot be valid, you cannot suggest a positive number equal to $\lvert x-y \rvert$ because $\lvert x-y \rvert$ is smaller than any such number (i.e. any $\epsilon \gt 0$).

I am guessing that your misunderstanding comes from reading the original statement as "if for every $\epsilon \gt0$ some $x,y$ are such that $\lvert x-y \rvert \lt \epsilon$ then they are $x=y$", which obviously cannot be true, as proven by your counter-example. But the correct original statement is that after you have taken some $x,y$ then you examine whether $\lvert x-y \rvert \lt \epsilon$ for every positive $\epsilon$. If so, $x=y$.