# Prove that if $a\leq b+\varepsilon$, $\forall \varepsilon>0$ then $a\leq b$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I was reading through the proof of this and I'm having trouble grasping what the contradiction is. Since $a\leq b+\varepsilon$ this is equivalent to $a-\varepsilon\leq b$. Suppose $b<a$ and taking $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}(a-b)$ we have $a-\varepsilon=a-\frac{1}{2}(a-b)=\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b>b$. At this point they state that this is a contradiction to the hypothesis but I don't see how it contradicts that. The contradiction or error I see is that then we have $b<a-\varepsilon\leq b\Rightarrow b<b$ which makes no sense. Although this doesn't appear to be the hypothesis. Also I was curious as to the intuition behind setting $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}(a-b)$.

Comment: for any two number $x,y$ ,  $x>y$ and $x\leq y$ can not hold together

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b

Comment: How is that +9 when my question is -1... After looking back at it the last line implies of the proof implies $1/2a > 1/2b$ and there's the contradiction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition: If $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon&gt;0$ then $a\leq b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume that $a-\varepsilon\leq b$ and derive $a-\varepsilon>b$.

The intuition is you want to to show that $a\not \leq b$. This means $a-b>0$. The $\frac12$ is just there for technical reasons. If you try with just $a-b$, it doesn't work quite as nicely.