# Prove that $a<b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ implies $a\le b$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> Prove that $a<b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ implies $a\le b$

Can anybody help me with this question? I am new to this topic.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? People will be happy to help if you show you put some effort into answering your own question. Hint: Assume, towards a contradiction, that $a<b+\epsilon$ $\forall\epsilon>0$ and $a>b$.

Comment: Also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906981/if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-each-epsilon0-then-a-le-b, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027284/x-y-are-real-xy-varepsilon-with-varepsilon0-how-to-prove-x-le-y, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559389/prove-that-if-a-leq-b-varepsilon-forall-varepsilon0-then-a-leq-b.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the question asked here is different (strict inequality assumption)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let us proceed with a proof by contradiction.

Assume that $a>b$. This implies $\frac{a-b}{2}>0$

Note that if we set $\epsilon=\frac{a-b}{2}$, then $$a<b+\frac{a-b}{2} \iff a<\frac{a+b}{2} \iff b>a$$
A contradiction to the assumption that $a>b$. Thus $a \le b$.

Comment: God thank you so much, i was becoming so confused.

Comment: @MrBob You're welcome. I recommend you proceed with a proof by contradiction with problems like these.

Comment: @MrBob Sorry, you're question is a duplicate. Sorry~

Comment: Yes ofcourse. Thank you