# Prove that for rational $x$,$y$ and $\epsilon$ if $|x-y| \leq \epsilon$ , $ \forall \epsilon > 0$ then $x=y$

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

I know that this is a repeated question, but I wanted to show my attempt.

Suppose $x \neq y$ and (wlog) $x > y$, then $x$ can be written as

$x = y + \delta$,  for some     ($\delta > 0$ and $\delta \in \mathbb Q$)

Therefore $|x-y| = \delta$.

But since $\delta <  \epsilon$ , $\forall \epsilon > 0, \epsilon \in \mathbb Q $ , and we assumed that $\delta > 0$ ; therefore contradiction arises. Hence $x=y$.

Is this a correct proof? I want to know what is missing or how to add more rigour in the last statement.

Comment: The step "$\delta<\epsilon,\forall \epsilon >0$ [...] and therefore a contradiction arises" could be improved, by simply choosing explicitly $\epsilon=\frac{\delta}{2}<\delta$. For the rest your proof is correct (although I don't see why you need the rationality assumption here)

Comment: I haven't constructed the reals yet.

Comment: Sure. Makes sense :)

Comment: But is it wrong / immature the way I wrote it? That since $\delta < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, and also that $\delta$ is positive; Hence the contradiction.

Comment: Yes and no: You are claiming that this is a contradiction without giving a proof of it, thus it is mathematically incorrect.

Comment: I don't see why $\delta < \epsilon$ gives a contradiction so you should point out why it is so.

Comment: Okay thanks :). I see what I skipped.

Comment: If the main purpose of your post is checking your proof (as opposed to asking for any solution), you should probably use the ([tag:proof-verification]) tag, see [the tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-verification/info).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition: If $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon&gt;0$ then $a\leq b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *...But since $\delta <  \epsilon$ , $\forall \epsilon > 0, \epsilon \in \mathbb Q $...*

This part is not right.

Make sure to use the *right* argument with the *right* inequality!

> Since $\delta >0$, there **exists** $\epsilon \in \Bbb Q$ such that $0 < \epsilon < \delta$ and therefore $\epsilon < |x-y| = \delta$, which is absurd.

Comment: Yeah right. I get the absurdity.