# For any $\epsilon$, if $\epsilon>0$ and $|x|<\epsilon$, then $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis

For any $\epsilon$, if $\epsilon>0$ and $|x|<\epsilon$, then $x=0$.

I understand that supposing  $\epsilon=\frac{x}{2}$ will lead to a contradiction, but let’s take a correct case:
Let $\epsilon=3$, then $x$ would have a whole set of values. Can you explain what is going on?

Comment: Quantifiers. You got them wrong: the right ones are "if $\lvert x\rvert < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$ then [...]"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition: If $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon&gt;0$ then $a\leq b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b)

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstand the role of "for any" there. Stated correctly, this is an assertion across all possible values of $\epsilon$, and as such: if it is always true that $|x|<\epsilon$ (no matter which $\epsilon $ is chosen) then we draw the conclusion that $x=0$

$x:(\forall \epsilon>0: |x|<\epsilon)\implies x=0$

Comment: Now get it , I am very grateful !

Answer (score 2):

As you have stated it,

For any $\epsilon$,  if $|x| <\epsilon$, then $x=0$,

the assertion is false and your counter-example shows that.

A true statement that may sound similar is:

If for every $\epsilon > 0$, $|x| <\epsilon$, then $x=0$.

This is a different statement that the first one.   This second statement says that if it is true that $|x|$ is less than every positive number, the $x=0$.  And that statement is true.

Answer (score -1):

If it is true for any real $\epsilon>0$, it will be true in particular, for any rational $r>0$,

so we will have, for any natural $n $,
$$|x|<\frac {1}{n+1} $$
or
$$-\frac {1}{n+1}<x <\frac {1}{n+1} $$

and the squeeze theorem gives
$$0\le x\le 0$$

The downvoter is a zam.

Comment: That's not answering the queston (although it's correct): the OP was merely confused about the quantifiers...

Comment: @ClementC. Feel free to delete it.

Comment: Uh? No. That's *your* answer.

Comment: @ClementC. It could help other users.

Comment: I like your method .