# Can someone clarify the therorem $x \lt y + \epsilon$ iff $x \leq y$

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem:

$ x \lt y + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ if and only if $x \leq y$

Suppose to the contrary that $x \lt y + \epsilon$ but $x \gt y$

Set $\epsilon_0 = x - y \gt 0$

Notice that $y + \epsilon = x$ Hence by the trichotomy property  This contradicts the hypothesis $\epsilon = \epsilon_0$. Thus $x \leq y$

I would like some clarification. I am wondering why this is proven by contradiction and what is $ \epsilon_0$ I know that it stands for the initial value of $ \epsilon$. It appears that the initial value is set to $0$ How does $y + \epsilon_0 = x$? I am guessing that $y + \epsilon$ cannot be be greater than x because it is like saying that x can be greater than itself which is false.

Comment: $\epsilon_0$ is a particular value you can plug in the statement about $\epsilon$ to get a contradiction

Comment: $y+\varepsilon_0=x$ because of the stipulation $\varepsilon_0=x-y$

Comment: When you said "Notice that $y+\varepsilon=x$", did you mean $y+\varepsilon_\color{red}0=x$?

Comment: Why did you write "Suppose to the contrary that $x\lt y+\epsilon$ but $x\gt y$" instead of "Suppose to the contrary that $x\lt y+\epsilon$ **for all $\epsilon\gt0$** but $x\gt y$"? Was that a typo?

Comment: Mathematicians yous indexes just to keep multiple variables apart.  They don't have anything to do with initial values.  If $x > y$ we know $x - y > 0$.  We assign the variable $\epsilon_0 = x-y$.  Now we have a statement that is about *all* positive numbers.  And $\epsilon_0$ is a positive number.  So it is true for $\epsilon_0$.  In making our statement we use $\epsilon$ to be about *any* positive number.  $\epsilon_0=x-y$ is a *specific* positive number.  We are using it to be *a* value of $\epsilon$ but the variable $\epsilon$ still refers to any positive value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition: If $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon&gt;0$ then $a\leq b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't about "initial values". This is about logic and about methods of proof.

In this part of the proof, you are trying to prove that the statement "for all $\epsilon > 0$, $x < y+\epsilon$" implies the statement "$x \le y$". There are of course many methods for proving that "P implies Q", and sometimes one method works better than another.

The method being used here is a proof by contrapositive: assume that "$x \le y$" is *false*, and so it's negation "$x > y$" is *true*; then use that to prove that the statement "for all $\epsilon > 0$, $x < y+\epsilon$" is *false*, i.e. to prove that its negation "there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x \ge y + \epsilon$" is *true*.

To prove an existence statement, the method is what I refer to as *The Hunt*. You must use what you know to *hunt down* an appropriate value of $\epsilon > 0$, to *find* the right value. Finding that value requires some mathematical imagination. And once you've found the right value of $\epsilon$, you use it to prove the inequality $x \ge y + \epsilon$.

So, what value of $\epsilon$ shall we use? What do we know about $x$ and $y$? Well.... we are assuming that $x > y$. It follows that $x - y > 0$... Could that be it?

Yes! Eureka! We've found it!

Let $\epsilon = x - y$.

From this we conclude that $x = y + \epsilon$, and therefore $x \ge y + \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

They way you transcribed this proof it has problems.

First of all it is not a proof of: $x < y+ \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ if and only if $x \le y$.

It is a proof only of: If $x < y+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ then $x \le y$.

Proof only goes in one direction.  You will need to do another proof for:  If $x \le y$ then $x < y+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Now to the proof:

> Suppose to the contrary

This means suppose $x< y + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0 \not \implies x\le y$.

This means suppose there are an $x$ and $y$ so that $x < y+\epsilon$ **for all $\epsilon > 0$**--

(In the proof as you wrote it you left at that this needs to be true *for all $\epsilon$* each and every one, not just one in particular.)

But somehow for this $x$ and $y$, it happens that $x \not \le y$.  That would mean that $x > y$ even though $x < y + \epsilon$ for all possible $\epsilon > 0$.

Since $x > y$ that mean $x-y > 0$.  Let's give $x-y$ a name.  I'll call it $BIPPYBOO$.

So $BIPPYBOO = x-y > 0$.

The proof you quoted called it $\epsilon_0$.  But I'm calling it $BIPPYBOO$.

> Notice that y+ϵ=x

That was simply a typo.  They meant  $y + BIPPYBOO = x$.

Which is obvious.  If $BIPPYBOO =x-y$ then $y + BIPPYBOO = x$.

> This contradicts the hypothesis ϵ=ϵ0.

This left out a very important word.

> This contradicts the hypothesis (that $x < y + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$) ***if*** we let $\epsilon = BIPPYBOO$.

Our hypothesis is that $x < y + \epsilon$ for *any* $\epsilon > 0$.  But $BIPPYBOO > 0$.  So this should be true if we set $epsilon = BIPPYBOO = x-y$.  We should have $x < y + BIPPYBOO$.

In other words we *should* have $x < y + (x-y)$ because $x-y > 0$ and for *ANY* $\epsilon > 0$ we have $x < y + \epsilon$.

But obvious $x < y+(x-y) = x$ is not true.

So our assumption, $x < y+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ means that $x > y$ is impossible  (because that would mean $x  < x +(y-x) = x$ which is just plain nutty).

So our assumption, $x < y+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ implies $x \le y$.

That's what the proof says.

And that's *half* the proof.

========

Now we have to prove if $x \le y$ then for any $\epsilon > 0$ we will always have $x < y+\epsilon$.

......

Which is easy.

If $\epsilon > 0$ then $y < y + \epsilon$.  But $x \le y$ and $y < y + \epsilon$ so by transitivity $x \le y + \epsilon$ and that is true for *any* $\epsilon > 0$.

++++++++

So if $x < y$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ then we know $x \le y$.

And if $x \le y$ the we know that $x < y+ \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

So that proves our theorem.