# Is the following statement true: two real numbers a and b are equal iff for every ε > 0, |a − b| < ε.

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following statement true?

> Two real numbers a and b are equal iff for every ε > 0, |a − b| < ε.

I got that if a and b are equal then |a-b|=0 which is less than ε.
But I'm not sure if the converse also holds.

Comment: otherwise $|a-b| < \frac{|a-b|}{2}$ is false

Comment: The only nonnegative real number smaller than every positive numebr is $0$.

Comment: @mathworker21: That's not how it works. ε can be any constant, e.g. 0.1 or 3.14, but it is  not a function f(a,b).

Comment: @MSalters that is how it works. you're fixing $a$ and $b$ and asking if it holds that $|a-b| < \epsilon$ *for all* $\epsilon > 0$. Included in "for all" is $\epsilon = \frac{|a-b|}{2}$.

Comment: @mathworker21: Fair point, after fixing a and b any function f(a,b) will also have a fixed value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition: If $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon&gt;0$ then $a\leq b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b)

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @user1110341 Again: that post, which you proposed as a duplicate of many questions, cannot be considered as such. It was about intuition, not proof. Moreover, though related, the question is not identical.

Answer (score 5):

The statement is correct.  Here is a proof of the converse.

Suppose that $a\neq b$.

Then $\epsilon:=|a-b|>0$ but we do not have $|a-b|<\epsilon$.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true because the condition is satisfied for *every* $\epsilon>0,$ no matter how little. When we say a *number* is less than such an $\epsilon,$ we simply mean that the number vanishes, or is $0.$

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is outright proven in [*Understanding Analysis* (2016 2 edn)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1493927116). pp 9 - 10.

> [image]

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.