# Two real numbers $a$ and $b$ are equal iff $| a - b |\leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon\gt0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Two real numbers $a$ and $b$ are equal iff $|a - b | \leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$

I know that it's true if it says "iff $| a - b | < \epsilon$". But if I use $\leq$, isn't that statement false? Because intuitively, since $\epsilon$  can't be $0$, $| a - b |$ might not be $0$ for all $\epsilon$

Comment: But $a$ and $b$ do not depend on $\epsilon$, so $|a-b|$ is a fixed number

Comment: The only non-negative number that is $\le\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ is $0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition: If $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon&gt;0$ then $a\leq b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b)

Answer (score 3):

If you know that it is true for $<$, then you can either adapt the proof for $\le$ or simply argue that if $\mid a - b \mid \leq \epsilon $  $\forall \epsilon >0$, then also $\mid a - b \mid < \epsilon $  $\forall \epsilon >0$. In fact, given $\epsilon >0$, then we know that $\mid a - b \mid \leq \epsilon/2 < \epsilon $.

Comment: In other words, the inequality $|a-b| \le \epsilon$ holds for all positive numbers $\epsilon$, even ones that are not called "$\epsilon$".

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is an $\epsilon$ such that $|a-b|=\epsilon$. Then with any smaller $\epsilon'$, you would have $|a-b|>\epsilon'$, which contradicts the hypothesis "for all".

In fact, equality never occurs because $\epsilon$ is nonzero.