# Showing that an implication is false

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, real-numbers, quantifiers

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ be two real numbers. Suppose that $$\forall \epsilon \gt0: a\le b+\epsilon$$ holds. I'm aware that the [correct implication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b?noredirect=1&lq=1) is $$\forall \epsilon \gt0: a\le b+\epsilon \implies a\le b,$$ but why is the implication $$\forall \epsilon \gt0: a\le b+\epsilon \implies a\lt b \tag{1}$$ false? What's the general strategy for showing implications like $(1)$ are false?

Comment: The general strategy is to find a counterexample. Here, if we let $a=b=0$, then $a\leq b+\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, but we do NOT have $a<b$.

Comment: @Feng Do you even need to set $a=b=0$? It seems rather obvious that $a\le a+\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon\gt 0$ and all $a$

Comment: @Feng Thanks. I think the important detail was $\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. So the complete implication is $$\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}\ \ \forall \epsilon \gt0: a\le b+\epsilon \implies a\lt b,$$ right?

Comment: For two mathematical statements $P$ and $Q$, the general strategy for showing that $P \Rightarrow Q$ is false is to demonstrate a case where $P$ is true **and** $Q$ is false.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for the comment. If you like you can add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Well... okay.  You have a $P \implies Q \text{ or } R$ and you want to know why $P \implies Q$ might not be true.  Find a case where $P$ is true but $Q$ is not.  As we know $P\implies Q\text{ or } R$ and we want $Q$ to be false so we will have $R$ true.  So consider $a =b$.  Then $a \le a+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$ and ... whoa! baby we are done.  $a\le a + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ but $a \not < a$ so our hypothesis is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary of the various comments:
$$\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}\ \ [(\forall \epsilon \gt0: a\le b+\epsilon) \implies a\lt b]$$
is false "because"
$$\exists a,b\in \mathbb{R}\ \ [(\forall \epsilon \gt0: a\le b+\epsilon) \text{ and } a\ge b]$$
is true. To prove it, take for instance $a=b=$ any number.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are righ about your intuition.

One logic observation: The $\varepsilon$ does not occur in $p: a<b$, therefore, the correct statement would be:
$\forall \varepsilon >0, a\le b+\varepsilon \implies a\le b.$

Let's prove that $\forall \varepsilon >0, a\le b+ \varepsilon \implies a\le b$.

Proof:
Suppose that $\forall \varepsilon >0, a\le b+\varepsilon$ but $a>b.$
Then $\exists p>0$ such that $a=b+p.$ Thus, $\forall \varepsilon >0, b+p\le b+ \varepsilon$, i.e. $\forall \varepsilon, p\le \varepsilon,$ ABSURD!

Answer (score 1):

Try to find a counterexample, so that the statement does NOT hold.
If we plug in $0$ for $a$ and $b$, we see that $a < b + \varepsilon$ holds, whereas $a<b$ (that is: $0<0$) does not hold.